# git gui fails on CentOS 6.5

Tags: git, centos6, git-gui

I have installed CentOS 6.5 and installed git and git-gui this morning.  Initially they worked but now I get the error message.

```
 $ sudo git gui
 No protocol specified
 Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
 No protocol specified
 Error in startup script: invalid command name "mc"
     while executing
 "mc "git-gui: fatal error""
     invoked from within
 "if {[catch {package require Tcl 8.4} err]
  || [catch {package require Tk  8.4} err]
 } {
    catch {wm withdraw .}
    tk_messageBox \
        -icon error \
        -typ..."
     (file "/usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui" line 34)
```

I did change the name of the host computer and thought that might be the problem.  However I removed and reinstalled git and git-gui and that did not fix the problem.

EDIT:

I edited /etc/hosts.  Its contents were

```
 127.0.0.1   newname.domain.com
 ::1         oldname
```

I changed it to
     127.0.0.1   newname.domain.com
     ::1         newname.domain.com

```
 git gui
```

works, albeit saying that it cannot open .git/PREPARE_COMMIT_MESSAGE  but

```
 sudo git gui
```

still gives the message above

Answer (score 0):

`couldn't connect to display` sounds as if you have no X server running, e.g. because you're trying to run `git gui` remotely via ssh but have X forwarding not enabled.

Comment: I'm not trying to run it remotely.  Everything is on the same box.  Thanks,

Comment: Or just not being the user who started X (i.e., don't being allowed to use that screen).

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer fixed the problem.  Maybe that is necessary after changing the computer name.